# How to execute two insert query in single statement in sqlite3

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to insert the values in two different tables in a single statement, first insert query in working second query is not working.

```
sqlite3_stmt * statement= NULL;
const char *dbpath =[databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mySqliteDB)== SQLITE_OK)
{
    for (PostObject * post in in_PostObject)
    {
**query**
        NSString * postSql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert or ignore into %@_post (postid,data,active) values (\"%@\",?,\"%d\");",tblPrefix,post.post_ID,post.active];

/*Appending First query with second query*/
        NSString * insertSQl =[postSql stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" insert into %@_forumuser (uid,utype,name) values (1,'parent','javid');",tblPrefix]];
        NSLog(@"%@",insertSQl);
        const char * insert_stmt=[insertSQl UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(mySqliteDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [post.jsonData UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            success =TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(mySqliteDB));
        }
    }
 }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(mySqliteDB);
```

Comment: make a method to process one more query

Comment: have you made `uid` as primary key (unique and not null) ? then it won't insert your record because you are passing   `uid` value `1` every time wile inserting record

Comment: I know that but for processing two query, I  have to open & close the DB twice.

Comment: @Sujay  I have created the uid without primary key

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return code from the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to make sure there aren't any problems.

Also you shouldn't need to open and close the database for each statement you want to execute, there you could process them as 2 statements

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(mySqliteDB, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) { 
    NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));

}
```